# Why does @@ROWCOUNT return 1 for a NULL statement using sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

If I run this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10) = NULL;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

I would expect to get 0, maybe even NULL would make sense.  But I don't get either, I get 1.  Why is 1 row affected by executing a NULL query?  If I pass in a "proper" (non_NULL) query then it works fine.

---

Background (for those that care): this is from a process that is supposed to generate some dynamic SQL to update one row and ONLY one row.  I need to check that 1 row has been affected, not 0 or 2 or more than 2.  It worked fine until somehow a NULL SQL statement managed to be generated, and this was seen as a success - oops!

The actual fix will be to check the SQL is non-NULL before running it, and treat a NULL statement the same way as a result other than 1.  But I was still curious why it behaved this way.

Comment: Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're assign `NULL` to your variable. Statements that make a simple assignment always set the `@@ROWCOUNT` value to 1.

See the example below. Because management studio can run its own queries on the connection and mess with the `@@ROWCOUNT` value it starts off selecting an empty result set to ensure the initial `@@ROWCOUNT` value is zero.

When there is no assignment the `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` returns `0` (the initial value has not been modified). Otherwise it returns `1`

```
/*Ensure @@ROWCOUNT starts off at 0*/
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 0;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

GO

/*Ensure @@ROWCOUNT starts off at 0*/
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 0;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10) = NULL;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

You can also try similar with a non zero initial value:

```
/*Ensure @@ROWCOUNT starts off at 3*/
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns 3

GO

/*Ensure @@ROWCOUNT starts off at 3*/
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10) = NULL;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns 1
```

Comment: Ignore my point about that it's not the `DECLARE`, I was completely forgetting that `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` would reset the count. D'oh!  This can far more easily be displayed here [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cfad350e0d6f9b42ef42931cc481a702), where the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` is `2` after the `EXEC`. Good job it's almost the end of the day.

Comment: Still, it is interesting that on instants I have access to, the code in your answer returns `1`, where as tools like DB<>fiddle and SQL Fiddle return `0`.

Comment: @Larnu - this is because SSMS executes a `SELECT @@SPID;` behind the scenes that sets the initial `@@ROWCOUNT` to `1`. Then both of the following leave it unchanged `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(10);EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith . That'll be why.

Answer (score 1):

*Please note that my answer was written purely from my experience of SQL Server Management Studio and does not accurately explain this behaviour. [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) has explained why this isn't true in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838435/why-does-rowcount-return-1-for-a-null-statement-using-sp-executesql/56838698#comment100230044_56838590) below.*

It looks like sp_executesql doesn't run at all with a null parameter, perhaps as a failsafe.

Try running "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT" alone in a batch and you'll see that it returns 1, regardless of the fact there is no current rowcount. It seems likely that 1 is the default return value and that's why you're seeing this.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. Try the following in powershell, you'll get a different result: `sqlcmd -S {YourServer} -Q "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;"`. @MartinSmith explained in the comments under @Sami's answer why `@@ROWCOUNT` returns `1` in SSMS when I was confused by it.